# "If" statements how to check out if multiple checkboxes is checked after a button click?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a button and 3 checkboxes, after button click I want to show a message if one or more of these checkboxs is checked. I prefer `Jquery` code if it's possible.
Thanks and any assistance it would be greatly appreciated.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".btn").click(function() {
    if ($('input[type="checkbox"]').is(":checked")) {
      if ($('input[name="box-1"]').is(":checked")) {
        $(".message").text("Box-1 is checked");
      }
      if ($('input[name="box-2"]').is(":checked")) {
        $(".message").text("Box-2 is checked");
      }
      if ($('input[name="box-3"]').is(":checked")) {
        $(".message").text("Box-3 is checked");
      }
    } else {
      $(".message").text("No box is checked");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" name="box-1">
<input type="checkbox" name="box-2">
<input type="checkbox" name="box-3">

<p class="message"></p>
<button class="btn">CLICK ME</button>
```

My code works fine, but the problem is the message shows only one `checkbox` is checked and I want to show for example:
If box-1 and box-3 are checked, message will be "box-1 and box-3 are cheched" and the same way with other checkboxes. Thanks and any assistance it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is even if multiple boxes are checked, the `.text()` method will default to the last `if` conditional where `is(":checked")` equals `true` always overwriting any previous cases that were also `true`.

What I would recommend is creating a variable to store the message you want to output, then concatenate onto it for each `if` check that is `true`. I imagine you want line breaks between each output, so just put `<br>` at the end of each line. Lastly, use `.html()` method to set the `.message` element instead of `.text()`.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".btn").click(function() {
    if ($('input[type="checkbox"]').is(":checked")) {
      //create message variable to hold html to be inserted
      var message = "";

      if ($('input[name="box-1"]').is(":checked")) {
        message += "Box-1 is checked<br>";
      }

      if ($('input[name="box-2"]').is(":checked")) {
        message += "Box-2 is checked<br>";
      }

      if ($('input[name="box-3"]').is(":checked")) {
        message += "Box-3 is checked<br>";
      }

      //set using '.html()' instead of '.text()' so you can insert breaks yourself
      $(".message").html(message);
    } else {
      $(".message").text("No box is checked");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" name="box-1">
<input type="checkbox" name="box-2">
<input type="checkbox" name="box-3">

<p class="message"></p>
<button class="btn">CLICK ME</button>
```

Comment: You're great, man! I used your code. Sir, it's simple and works fine! my code was just missing this simple trick by putting that show message into a variable and using += in If statement. but I didn't get it simply. So there is no problem now. Thank you so much brother for the help and your effort. And your answer has been appreciated and accepted.

Answer (score 2):

Check the length of how many checkboxes are checked? And use [`.map()`](https://api.jquery.com/map/) this way:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".btn").click(function() {
    if ($('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length > 0) {
      $(".message").text("Success! You have checked " + [...$('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').map(function () {
        return this.name;
      })].join(", ") + ".");
    } else {
      $(".message").text("Sorry! You should check at least 3 checkboxes!");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" name="box-1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="box-2" />
<input type="checkbox" name="box-3" />

<p class="message"></p>
<button class="btn">CLICK ME</button>
```

**What does `.map()` function do?**

> `.map()` Pass each element in the current matched set through a function, producing a new jQuery object containing the return values.

**Preview**

[image: Can you check this preview?]

Comment: I think you didn't understand what I want. I want if one of the checkboxs is checked message shows its name, and if 2 boxes are checked message shows their names etc... Thank you sir for the help.

Comment: @mowx Thanks, but did you try running the snippet, it does work. Did you see when you select it, it shows the name. I understood it correctly.

Comment: @mowx [Can you check this preview?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YiRHY.gif)

Comment: @mowx I have added preview in the answer.

Comment: That's done! Thank you sir for your help. Your answer is also great and works completely fine. So I chose the answer that fits my code. have a great days.

Comment: @mowx Super! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

First find all of the checked boxes, then join them together with `and`, the check if there are spaces, if so, then add "are" for plural, if not then add "is" for singular, then if there is an output, add "checked." to it. Finally, if output exists, set the textbox to it, if not, then return "No box is checked".

```js
$(function() {
  $(".btn").click(function() {
    let output = [...$('input[type="checkbox"]:checked')].reduce((acc, _, ind) => acc ? (acc + ` and Box-${ind+1}`) : `Box-${ind+1}`, "");
    if (output.split` `.length>1) output += " are ";
    else if (output) output += " is ";
    if (output) output += "checked."
    
    $(".message").text(output || "No box is checked");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" name="box-1">
<input type="checkbox" name="box-2">
<input type="checkbox" name="box-3">

<p class="message"></p>
<button class="btn">CLICK ME</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    $(function() {
      const mapNameToText = {
        'box-1': 'Box-1',
        'box-2': 'Box-2',
        'box-3': 'Box-3',
      }

      let checkedBoxes = [];

      $(".btn").click(function() {
        checkedBoxes = [];

        $.each(mapNameToText, (key, value) => {
          if($('input[name=' + key + ']').is(":checked")) {
            checkedBoxes.push(value);
          }
        });

        if(checkedBoxes.length) {
          $(".message").text(`${checkedBoxes.join(', ')} ${checkedBoxes.length > 1 ? 'are' : 'is'} checked`);
        } else {
          $(".message").text("No box is checked");
        }
      });
    });
```

Comment: What does this mean? Any explanation or context please? Don't give just a solution.